# How to proceed from the below mentioned scenario

Tags: partitioning, kernel, system-settings

1. I tried to add a new system call for the linux kernel v5.9 for what I have done all the steps till kernel configuration.
2. Next, I ran make menuconfig and saved the default settings and exited from he config window then the kernel compilation began which took around an hour.
3. After this it terminated saying that no more space is left on the disk due to which it failed.
4. I tried to somehow resize the partition size so that ubuntu boots up otherwise ubuntu was not booting up after 3rd point.
5. Now what should i do to complete the menuconfig part of the kernel and also free up the space next as I suppose it shouldn't be that big to leave no space inthe disk or how to revert back to the old configuration of my ubuntu system where kernel v5.4.48 was running leaving enough space in the disk??